# When try to Installing Scrapy on Windows 10 facing (WinError 3)

Tags: python, windows, scrapy, anaconda

When I'm trying to install Scrapy on Windows 10, I'm facing a WinError 3.

Conda version: 4.5.12
Conda-build version: 3.17.6
Python version: 3.7.1.final.0

I'm facing these errors:

> [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\PlatformSDK\lib'
>
> [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\lib'

using both commands:

```
pip install Scrapy

conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
```

I did some quick googling but could not find a solution which worked. Any ideas on what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `c++ complier` in `visual studio 2015`.

Try to install it from here. [visual studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)

After then try this:

```
pip install scrapy
conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
```

Comment: installing visual studio 2015 libraries already but it is not working

Comment: Are you install it your own environment or not?

Comment: Environment install already but its not working later i'm install visual stdio library C++ it take some time but its working.. Thank you very much